# Concurency with event loop (async/await) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm a bit confused. Asyncio has single-threaded event loop. Every co-routine runs in it. If I have coroutine that doesn't have any await/yield, such co-routine should be atomic. Why I should ever syncronouse access to global variable (as example of shared resource)?

For example,

```py
import asyncio

global_var = 0

async def coroutine1():
    global global_var
    global_var += 1

async def coroutine2():
    global global_var
    global_var -= 1

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(coroutine1(), coroutine2())

asyncio.run(main())
```

I don't see any problem.

Furthermore, if the co-routine does yields control, it yields it to event-loop that resumes another co-routine (if available). So, also in this case no synchronization is required.

What I got wrong?

**EDIT**:

```py
import asyncio
import time
async def task1():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Task 1 done")

async def task2():
    await asyncio.sleep(7)
    print("Task 2 done")

async def main():
    t_0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(task1(), task2())
    print((int)(time.time() - t_0))
    print("All tasks completed")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

Task 1 done

Task 2 done

7

All tasks completed

Hmm, it takes max(5,7)=7 seconds. It seems that's yielding control is done not only without noticeable overhead, but it "seems" that's they progress concurrently. I still don't get it...

**EDIT**:

In one hand they run on event loop sequentially, in another hands it "seems" that they run concurrently. How this effect is achieved?

Comment: So what is the question? How the `task1()`/`task2()` run in parallel?

Comment: @AndrejKesely in one hand they run on event loop sequentially, in another hands it "seems" that they run concurrently. How this effect is achieved? Added also to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
Task 1 and Task 2 will be pushed into event_loop (can be seen as a queue)
Python will run the coroutines one by one, so there will be no resource competition

Case 2:
When the code runs into async sleep, it hangs and waits for the time to come
So the second 0, task 1 and task 2 will be suspended
At 5 seconds, task 1 wakes up and prints
At 7 seconds, task 2 wakes up

Tasks run concurrently, but not in parallel
Only one task will run at a time, but the main interpreter can be released by coroutines while awaiting for something

Here is an article about async, you can have a look https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#asynchronous-code